# Respaldo de base de datos postgresql desde java

Tags: java

En la vista tengo un campo texto en el cual indico la dirección en donde guardara el archivo junto al nombre que desea colocarle.

```
String direccion = vista.txtFileRespaldar.getText();
```

Este lo convierto en tipo `file` de la siguiente manera:

```
File dir= new File (direccion);
```

Compruebo si la dirección es valida y procedo al respaldo de la db:

```
if(direccion.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Debe indicar una ruta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}else if(dir.exists()){
    boolean hecho=modelo.BD_backup(direccion);
    if(hecho){
        System.out.println("terminado backup " + dir);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Error al intentar realizar el backup", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("error en backup" + dir);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Debe indicar una ruta valida", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Indico cualquier ruta en mi PC y me dice que la ruta no es valida, es decir, el ultimo `else`.

Intente indicando la ruta y nombre de un archivo **.backup** ya creado y realizo el respaldo correctamente.

Alguna idea del ¿Por que?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando crea el directorio

```
File dir= new File (direccion);
```

Crea la instancia, pero hace falta crear los directorios físicos

```
dir.mkdir();
```

o

```
dir.mkdirs();
```

según el caso que requieras y si lo que deseas es crear un archivo debes usar

```
File file = new File(nombreArchivo);
file.createNewFile();
```

fuente http://devtroce.com/2010/03/26/verificar-y-crear-directorio-con-java/

Comment: En el campo indico algo como **D:\Mis Documentos\respaldo_x.backup**, haciendo lo que dices me genera una carpeta con el nombre **respaldo_x.backup**.

Comment: ok, `dir.mkdir();` genera una carpeta un folder, para crear un archivo usas `File file = new File();` y posterior a esto creas el archivo `file.createNewFile();`

Comment: Modifica tu respuesta y coloca lo de `file.createNewFile();`, fue lo que soluciono mi problema.