# Problema al crear ficheros y archivos en JAVA (luego de crear instalador)

Tags: java, windows

Pues el problema es el siguiente:

Al programar con `Netbeans` y ejecutar el programa todo funciona bien. Me crea una carpeta y un archivo `txt` como debe de ser. Pero luego de crear el instalador de la aplicación, e instalarla (en `C:`) no me crea ninguna carpeta o archivo `txt`.

No sé si el problema sea porque hay que darle algunos permisos administrativos (o algo así) en el código, para que pueda crear los ficheros, etc.

Soy novato en la programación y cualquier comentario lo agradezco de antemano.

---

La dirección es la correcta

[image: La dirección es la correcta]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En teoría si no existe la carpeta la crearía.

Aquí el código:

```java
public class respaldo {
  JFileChooser selector = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
  String user="root";
  String pass="";
  String password="";
  String host ="localhost";
  String bd="veterinaria";
  String path="C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe";
  String backup="mysqldump --user="+user+" --password="+password+" -v "+bd+" > "+path;
  private String extension=".sql";
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  String dir;
  correo c = new correo();
  String nombrearchivo ;

  public void respaldar() {
    Date fecha = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");   
    dir=""+selector.getCurrentDirectory();
    try {    
      File fl=new File(dir);
      File fl2= new File(dir,"respaldos");
      fl2.mkdir(); 
      File file=new File(fl2,formateador.format(fecha));
      nombrearchivo = file.getName();
      path=file.getAbsolutePath()+extension;       
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,path);
      String command = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --user="+user+" --password="+pass+" "+bd+" -r"+path;
      rt.exec(command);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(respaldo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: La causa del problema podrias ser por multiples motivos, como tu dices pueden ser permisos, otro problema es que el path sea inadecuado,etc, dar una respuesta con la poca informacion que proporciones seria imposible, añade informacion como por ejemplo el codigo, ademas siempre es bueno mostrar mensajes del estado de la aplicacion.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Perdón por eso... ya corregí el cuerpo :)

Comment: Creo que hace falta usar un `File.createNewFile()`, revisa la siguiente entrada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97650/respaldo-de-base-de-datos-postgresql-desde-java/97660#97660

Comment: El problema que sufres es que no estás escapando la ruta al ejecutar el comando `mysqldump`, por lo que la ruta (que contiene espacios en blanco) se está dividiendo en dos parámetros. Redactando respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que sufres es debido a que no estás escapando de forma alguna la ruta que proporcionas al [parámetro `-r` (result file) de `mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file). Eso provoca que se divida en varios parámetros diferentes, provocando un funcionamiento no esperado.

Ejecución generada:

```
mysqldump -u usuario -pclave bbdd -r C:\Program Files (86)\...
```

Es probable que en la raíz de `C:` hayas creado un archivo llamado `Program` que contenga la exportación (`C:\Program`). El resto de ruta se interpreta como nombres de [tablas a exportar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-syntax):

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

Para permitir que Java decida la forma más adecuada de escapar los parámetros de acuerdo con el sistema operativo que se esté usando hay que hacer uso de la llamada [`Runtime.exec(String[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29):

```
rt.exec(new String[] {
    "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump",
    "-u", user,
    "-p" + pass,
    bd,
    "-r",
    path
});
```